# How to dynamically load reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app, code-splitting

I have three mini-website within a site. I want the main reducer to store auth information. And, the respective mini-website to store it's own reducers. So, when one mini-site is browsed the respective template/component and reducers must be loaded. Note that, I am doing this as the stores among mini-sites are exhaustive

similar to this [github repo](http://github.com/insin/react-examples/tree/master/). This repo contains old react-router version. I want it to work with react-router-v4 and with `create-react-app`

How do I dynamically load reducers related to particular component when loading the Component dynamically?

I am creating react project using `create-react-app` and these are the package versions

```
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
```

This is how I am dynamically loading component

```
class DynamicImport extends React.Component {
  state = { component: null };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props
      .load()
      .then(module => this.setState(() => ({ component: module.default })));
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.component);
  }
}

const Admin = props => (
  <DynamicImport
    load={() => import("../views/Admin")}
  >
    {Component =>
      Component === null ? <div>Loading</div> : <Component {...props} />
    }
  </DynamicImport>
);
```

and in render()

```
<Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
```

Is there an easier way to load/inject respective reducers when the component is rendered

Comment: what's your use case? why don't you predefine and register all reducers instead of injecting them dynamically?

Comment: I have three mini-website within a site. I want the main reducer to store auth information. And, the respective mini-website to store it's own reducers. So, when one mini-site is browsed the respective template/component and reducers must be loaded. Note that, I am doing this as the stores among mini-sites are exhaustive.

Comment: @lustoykov I want something similar to this https://github.com/insin/react-examples/tree/master/code-splitting-redux-reducers . But, this is using older version of React-router

Comment: ah I see... nice - so why don't you let the dynamically injected component call a function to do `store.replaceReducer(configureReducers(reducers))` on its componentDidMount callback? or you can call it after the load() has completed as well

Comment: did you mean this?
`componentDidMount() { store.replaceReducer(configureReducers('/path/to/new/reducer') 
 this.props.load().then(module => this.setState(() => ({ component: module.default }))); }`

Comment: no, you want to replace them after a component has been dynamically injected and not only once. So each time a component has been injected, a replacement has to take place

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Did you mean in the actual component's componentdidmount? Where do I dynamically import Reducer, then?

Comment: @lustoykov could you write a sample code illustrating where and how to configure the reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @lustoykov suggested, the way to load reducers dynamically is by `store.replaceReducer(configureReducers(reducer))`

This, easy to follow article explains how to setup dynamic reducers in detail. https://tylergaw.com/articles/dynamic-redux-reducers/

Here is my github repo with a completed solution. It follows the steps as given in article. https://github.com/sabbiu/dynamic-reducers-for-react/

Comment: How can I implement the same with typescript?

Comment: The basic functionality is as given in the repo above. I have no experience with TypeScript. But, I do not think it will be difficult as it is a static type checking and core functionality will remain the same. I would be more than happy to help if you find any difficulties in understanding the code.

Comment: The latest version doesn't not support the passing of the store in the context as it's being used in the above example. Hence we won't be able to invoke the context.store.injectReducer. I am unable to find a way to get this part working for the recent version.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file

Comment: "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",

Comment: The error you are encountering might be due to react-redux v6+. As you can see here, [react-redux v6.0.0 changelogs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0), it has major changes which I have not looked into. If you downgrade react-redux to v5 then, it might work.